# Using the key "MYDICT.get" as a means of sorting the Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.x

What does the following syntax do differently than simply sorting the list without a key? `MYDICT` is a dictionary

`sorted(MYDICT, key = MYDICT.get)`

Comment: Dictionaries are unsorted in Python 2.x.  Also, I can't figure out what you are even asking.  Can you post what `LIST` is?

Comment: @chrisz, see my answer -- it took me a few minutes to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a short way of sort `dict` keys by value.  Here is why:**

```
mydict = {"a": 3, "b": 2, "c": 1}

sorted(mydict, key=mydict.get)
```

Output is:

```
['c', 'b', 'a']
```

The reason is that the `key=` argument to `sorted()` is expecting a callable function that takes the current list item as the argument and returns the value to use to sort that item with.

In the above case, `mydict.get(key)` will return the value of `key`.

When you iterate over a `dict`, it only iterates over the keys, not the values.

Putting it all together, `sorted(mydict)` is iterating over and returning a list containing the sorted **keys** of mydict, but using `mydict.get(key)`, which returns the **value** of that key, to do the sorting with.